# How can I test whether connection to the given host/port is established in Bash?

Tags: bash, networking, arch-linux

Currently I'm using netstat for this:

```
if netstat -an | grep ESTABLISHED | grep $address:$port > /dev/null; then
    # command
fi
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: You can use `grep -q` instead of sending stdout to /dev/null.

Comment: Comment you've marked as approved answer is flawed — `grep` and IP-addresses are pitfall, since usual notation for IP-addresses has dots inside. See my comments: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21020/how-can-i-test-whether-connection-to-the-given-host-port-is-established-in-bash/21060#comment49428_21060 P. S. I'd mark as answer this one:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36354/6622

Comment: I don't agree that there is such flaw (see comments). But JodieC's answer *does* look better, just as [Gilles' one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21063/9382).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as elegance is concerned, I'd modify two things in your command:

- As mentioned in comment by Chris, you can use `-q` instead of output redirection.
- Use one `grep` instead of two:

  ```
  if netstat -an | grep -q " $address:$port .* ESTABLISHED"; then
  ```

Comment: I advice not using `grep`, when there's no need in regexps `fgrep` fits better.

Comment: @poige But here you do have a regexp. And using `fgrep` (or rather `grep -F`, since `fgrep` is deprecated) in this case is useless also due to negligible potential speed benefit in a single invocation. It would take far more time to type a (longer) working filter with `fgrep` - and it would need to use pipe, just as in the OP's example.

Comment: My bad, I've overlooked it.

Regarding fgrep:

1) GNU's man can call it deprecated (whatever), but neither does BSD's or Solaris'. So I don't care typing extra `-f` to grep, neither advice doing that to anyone. :)

Comment: 2) Lots of people tend blindly use `grep` and spending theirs time in escaping its spec. symbols, or what's a way worse, getting wrong results having forgotten to escape such symbs.. Look, `$address` you've used in your `grep` actually has that spec. symbs. — dots. That's a flaw, actually.

Comment: 3) Fgrep is noticable faster on huge files, like log files, for e. g..

So, once again my advice is: use fgrep as much as possible instead of grep — get used to using it.

Comment: @poige I agree with your reasons for using `fgrep` where possible, and especially with large amounts of data. But again, this scenario is not such a case.

Comment: Surely it's not the case #3. It's the case #2 instead.

Comment: @poige I can only partially agree with your point about dots. Yes, they will match any single character. But **practically** it does not matter in this usecase. Give an example where the dots in `$adr:` would make `grep` match any valid IP other than `$adr`. I say it is not possible.

Comment: @poige The dots can't be a problem, but I've just noticed an actual flaw of grepping for `"$addr:$port"`: there needs to be a space at the beginning - otherwise, for example, grepping for `92.168.2.2` could match `192.168.2.2` as a false positive. (now fixed in the answer)

Comment: Not only at the beginning, there's a port as well where, say `:80` would match ":80anything" — that's why I support solution using `ss`. And yeah, when there's terminator like `:`, dots can be safe. But otherwise `192.168.1.4` perfectly matches the whole 192.168.104, for e. g..

Answer (score 2):

[`lsof`](http://people.freebsd.org/~abe/) should do the job. Ask it to give you machine-parseable output with the `-F` option.

```
lsof -n -i @${hostname}:${port} -F nT | grep '^TST=ESTABLISHED$'
```

If you need more information:

```
lsof -n -i -F nT | awk '
    function host_port(s, a) {
        match(s, /:[^:]*$/);
        a["host"] = substr(s, 1, RSTART-1);
        a["port"] = substr(s, RSTART+1);
    }
    sub(/^p/,"") {pid = $0}
    sub(/^n/,"") {
        split($0, endpoints, "->");
        host_port(endpoints[1], from);
        host_port(endpoints[2], to);
    }
    /^TST=ESTABLISHED$/ {
        print "Established from", from["host"] ":" from["port"],
              "to", to["host"] ":" to["port"]
    }
'
```

Answer (score 2):

with `ss`:

```
if ss -n -o state established '( dport = $hostname:$portnumber )'|awk 'NR==2{exit 0}END{exit 1}';then
```

Answer (score 1):

That works well enough for now, for Linux.

On other UNIX systems (the ones I have my hands on are Mac OS X and Solaris) the port is separated by `.` instead of `:`.

And this will most likely fail for any IPv6 connection. `netstat` truncates IPv6 addresses, so make sure to use `--wide`. But again, that's not a portable option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lsof` instead of `netstat`: something like this: `sudo /usr/sbin/lsof -i tcp@1.2.3.4:80`, but lsof is only available for root user and often not installed by default, so it's additional external dependency.