# How do I grep for multiple patterns with pattern having a pipe character?

Tags: shell, grep, regular-expression, quoting

I want to find all lines in several files that match one of two patterns. I tried to find the patterns I'm looking for by typing

```
grep (foo|bar) *.txt
```

but the shell interprets the `|` as a pipe and complains when `bar` isn't an executable.

How can I grep for multiple patterns in the same set of files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grep: how to add an “OR” condition?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25821/44425)

Comment: grep 'word1\|word2\|word3' /path/to/file

Answer (score 1079, accepted):

First, you need to protect the pattern from expansion by the shell. The easiest way to do that is to put single quotes around it. Single quotes prevent expansion of anything between them (including backslashes); the only thing you can't do then is have single quotes in the pattern.

```
grep -- 'foo*' *.txt
```

(also note the `--` end-of-option-marker to stop some `grep` implementations including GNU `grep` from treating a file called `-foo-.txt` for instance (that would be expanded by the shell from `*.txt`) to be taken as an option (even though it follows a non-option argument here)).

If you do need a single quote, you can write it as `'\''` (end string literal, literal quote, open string literal).

```
grep -- 'foo*'\''bar' *.txt
```

Second, grep supports at least¹ two syntaxes for patterns. The old, default syntax ([basic regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended)) doesn't support the alternation (`|`) operator, though some versions have it as an extension, but written with a backslash.

```
grep -- 'foo\|bar' *.txt
```

The portable way is to use the newer syntax, [extended regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended). You need to pass the `-E` option to `grep` to select it (formerly that was done with the `egrep` separate command²)

```
grep -E -- 'foo|bar' *.txt
```

Another possibility when you're just looking for any of several patterns (as opposed to building a complex pattern using disjunction) is to pass multiple patterns to `grep`. You can do this by preceding each pattern with the `-e` option.

```
grep -e foo -e bar -- *.txt
```

Or put patterns on several lines:

```
grep -- 'foo
bar' *.txt
```

Or store those patterns in a file, one per line and run

```
grep -f that-file -- *.txt
```

Note that if `*.txt` expands to a single file, `grep` won't prefix matching lines with its name like it does when there are more than one file. To work around that, with some `grep` implementations like GNU `grep`, you can use the `-H` option, or with any implementation, you can pass `/dev/null` as an extra argument.

---

<sup>¹ some `grep` implementations support even more like perl-compatible ones with `-P`, or *augmented* ones with `-X`, `-K` for ksh wildcards...</sup>

<sup>² while `egrep` has been deprecated by POSIX and is sometimes no longer found on some systems, on some other systems like Solaris when the POSIX or GNU utilities have not been installed, then `egrep` is your only option as its `/bin/grep` supports none of `-e`, `-f`, `-E`, `\|` or multi-line patterns</sup>

Comment: As a sidenote -- when the patterns are fixed, you should really get into the habit of `fgrep` or `grep -F`, for small patterns the difference will be negligible but as they get longer, the benefits start to show...

Comment: @TC1, yeah, people often forget that `grep` uses regexp syntax —  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21020/how-can-i-test-whether-connection-to-the-given-host-port-is-established-in-bash/21060#comment49428_21060

Comment: @TC1 fgrep is deprecated according to man page

Comment: @TC1 Whether `grep -F` has an actual performance benefit depends on the grep implementation: some of them apply the same algorithm anyway, so that `-F` makes a difference only to the time spent parsing the pattern and not to the time searching. GNU grep isn't faster with `-F`, for example (it also has a bug that makes `grep -F` slower in multibyte locales — the same constant pattern with `grep` is actually significantly faster!). On the other hand BusyBox grep does benefit a lot from `-F` on large files.

Comment: Perhaps it should be mentioned that for more complicated patterns where alternation is only to be for a *part* of the regular expression, it can be grouped with "\\(" and "\\)" (the escaping is for the default "basic regular expressions")  (?).

Comment: Note that `egrep` predates `grep -E`. It is not GNU specific (it certainly has nothing to do with Linux). Actually, you'll still find systems like Solaris where the default `grep` still doesn't support `-E`.

Comment: When all else fails, individual `-e` options is the simplest and safest bet

Comment: i always forget the `-E` and have to resort the google/here.  but i think i like the multiple instances version with `-e` and am going to try to remember that one

Answer (score 148):

```
egrep "foo|bar" *.txt
```

or

```
grep "foo\|bar" *.txt
grep -E "foo|bar" *.txt
```

selectively citing the man page of gnu-grep:

```
   -E, --extended-regexp
          Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, see below).  (-E is specified by POSIX.)

Matching Control
   -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
          Use PATTERN as the pattern.  This can be used to specify multiple search patterns, or to protect  a  pattern
          beginning with a hyphen (-).  (-e is specified by POSIX.)
```

(...)

```
   grep understands two different versions of regular expression syntax: “basic” and “extended.”  In  GNU grep,  there
   is  no  difference  in  available  functionality  using  either  syntax.   In  other implementations, basic regular
   expressions are less powerful.  The following description applies to extended regular expressions; differences  for
   basic regular expressions are summarized afterwards.
```

In the beginning I didn't read further, so I didn't recognize the subtle differences:

```
Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions
   In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose their special meaning; instead  use  the
   backslashed versions \?, \+, \{, \|, \(, and \).
```

I always used egrep and needlessly parens, because I learned from examples. Now I learned something new. :)

Comment: In case can I use it as follows: `egrep "[f]oo|[b]ar" *.txt` due to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9375940/2402577 @user unknown

Comment: @alper: It doesn't make sense to me. In your linked question, it is a hack to stop the command itself from appearing in the ps-list, but you're grepping in a txt-file. With these brackets, you may grep for alternatives, but don't present some. `egrep "[nm]oon|[jt]ar" *.txt` would find moon, noon, jar or tar. For linked example, I would use pgrep as suggested by someone else, or ps -C command, if the name of the command was command. Only in this specific case, grepping for "terminal" at different positions, this hack is pretty clever. For options, use: `echo "erminal" | egrep "[tT]?erminal"`

Answer (score 29):

Like TC1 said, `-F` seems to be usable option:

```
$> cat text
some text
foo
another text
bar
end of file

$> patterns="foo
bar" 

$> grep -F "${patterns}" text
foo
bar
```

Comment: @poige I didn't know about the $'foo\nbar' option, not sure how expansion works here, need to look up, but thank you, that is really useful.

Comment: Nice! This option also seems to make it run much faster (since it disables regex).

Answer (score 18):

Firstly, you need to use quotes for special characters.  Second, even so, `grep` will not understand alternation directly; you would need to use `egrep`, or (with GNU `grep` only) `grep -E`.

```
egrep 'foo|bar' *.txt
```

(The parentheses are unnecessary unless the alternation is part of a larger regex.)

Comment: Actually, `grep -E` is more standard than `egrep`.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't need regular expressions, it's much faster to use `fgrep` or `grep -F` with multiple -e parameters, like this:

```
fgrep -efoo -ebar *.txt
```

`fgrep` (alternatively `grep -F`) is much faster than regular grep because it searches for fixed strings instead of regular expressions.

Comment: Please see also the comments on this page mentioning that `fgrep` is deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

You can try the below command to get the result:

```
egrep 'rose.*lotus|lotus.*rose' some_file
```

Answer (score 5):

Pipe (`|`) is a special shell character, so it either needs to be escaped (`\|`) or quoted as per manual ([`man bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)):

> **Quoting is used to remove the special meaning** of certain characters or words to the shell. It can be used to disable special treatment for special characters, to prevent reserved words from being recognized as such, and to prevent parameter expansion.
>
> **Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value** of all characters within the quotes
>
> A non-quoted backslash (`\`) is the escape character.

See: [Which characters need to be escaped in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15783701/55075)

Here are few examples (using tools not mentioned yet):

- Using [`ripgrep`](http://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/):

  - `rg "foo|bar" *.txt`
  - `rg -e foo -e bar *.txt`
- Using [`git grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep):

  - `git grep --no-index -e foo --or -e bar`

    <sup>Note: It also supports Boolean expressions such as `--and`, `--or` and `--not`.</sup>

For AND operation per line, see: [How to run grep with multiple AND patterns?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55359/21471)

For AND operation per file, see: [How to check all of multiple strings or regexes exist in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49762772/55075)

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: if you want to do more things after matching one of the multiple patterns, enclose them as in `\(pattern1\|pattern2\)`

example: I want to find all the places where a variable that contains the name 'date' is defined as a String or int. (e.g., "int cronDate =" or "String textFormattedDateStamp ="):

```
cat myfile | grep '\(int\|String\) [a-zA-Z_]*date[a-zA-Z_]* ='
```

With `grep -E`, you don't need to escape the parentheses or the pipe, i.e., `grep -E '(int|String) [a-zA-Z_]*date[a-zA-Z_]* ='`

Answer (score 3):

I had access logs where the dates were stupidly formatted: [30/Jun/2013:08:00:45 +0200]

But I needed to display it as: 30/Jun/2013 08:00:45

The problem is that using "OR" in my grep statement, I was receiving the two match expressions on two separate lines.

Here is the solution:

```
grep -in myURL_of_interest  *access.log  | \
grep -Eo '(\b[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{4}|[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}\b)'   \
| paste - - -d" " > MyAccess.log
```

Answer (score 3):

A cheap and cheerful way to grep for multiple patterns:

```
$ echo "foo" > ewq ; echo "bar" >> ewq ; grep -H -f ewq *.txt ; rm ewq
```

Comment: It could benefit from an explanation.

Comment: The explanation is that grep's `-f` option takes a file with multiple patterns.
Instead of creating a temporary file (that you may forget to delete afterwards), just use the shell's process substitution:
`grep -f <(echo foo; echo bar) *.txt`

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this.

1. `grep 'foo\|bar' *.txt`
2. `egrep 'foo|bar' *.txt`
3. `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt" | xargs grep 'foo\|bar'`
4. `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt" | xargs egrep 'foo|bar'`

The 3rd and 4th option will grep only in the files and avoid directories having `.txt` in their names.
So, as per your use-case, you can use any of the option mentioned above.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
root@gateway:/home/sshuser# aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-2db0459d |grep 'STATE\|TAG'

**STATE**   80      stopped

**STATE**REASON     Client.UserInitiatedShutdown    Client.UserInitiatedShutdown: User initiated shutdown

**TAGS**    Name    Magento-Testing root@gateway:/home/sshuser#
```

Answer (score 1):

to add to [@geekosaur's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37314/100397), if you have multiple patterns that also contain tabs and space you use the following command

```
grep -E "foo[[:blank:]]|bar[[:blank:]]"
```

where `[[:blank:]]` is RE character class that represents either a space or a tab character