# How can I grep for this or that (2 things) in a file?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have a file that has "then"'s and "there"'s.

I can

```
$ grep "then " x.x
x and then some
x and then some
x and then some
x and then some
```

and I can

```
$ grep "there " x.x
If there is no blob none some will be created
```

How can I search for both in one operation?
I tried

```
$ grep (then|there) x.x
```

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

and

```
grep "(then|there)" x.x
durrantm.../code
# (Nothing)
```

Comment: linked, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37313/how-do-i-grep-for-multiple-patterns-with-pattern-having-a-pipe-character

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You need to put the expression in quotation marks. The error you are receiving is a result of bash interpretting the `(` as a special character.

Also, you need to tell grep to use extended regular expressions.

```
$ grep -E '(then|there)' x.x
```

Without extended regular expressions, you have to escape the `|`, `(`, and `)`. Note that we use single quotation marks here. Bash treats backslashes within double quotation marks specially.

```
$ grep '\(then\|there\)' x.x
```

The grouping isn't necessary in this case.

```
$ grep 'then\|there' x.x
```

It would be necessary for something like this:

```
$ grep 'the\(n\|re\)' x.x
```

Comment: See also `grep $'then\nthere'` and `grep -e then -e there`. Note that `\|` is not standard in BREs. The rest is. Bash treats backslashes specially within double quotes only before `"`, `$`, `\ `, `\`` and newline.

Comment: What is the purpose of `x.x`?

Comment: @alex I believe that is intended to represent the file, e.g., `allMySuperDuperSecretPasswords.txt`

Answer (score 9):

Just a quick addendum, most flavours have a command called egrep which is just grep with -E. I personally like much better to type

```
egrep "i(Pod|Pad|Phone)" access.log
```

Than to use grep -E

Answer (score 3):

The stuff documented under REGULAR EXPRESSIONS in the (or at least, my) man page is actually for *extended* regexps;

> grep understands three different versions of regular expression
>   syntax: “basic,” “extended” and  “perl.”  In  GNU grep,  there  is  no
>   difference  in  available
>          functionality  between basic and extended syntaxes.  In other implementations, basic regular expressions are less powerful.  **The
>   following description applies to
>          extended regular expressions;** differences for basic regular expressions are summarized afterwards.

But grep does not use them by default -- you need the `-E` switch:

```
grep "(then|there)" x.x
```

Because (from the man page again):

> Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions
>
> In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions
>   \?, +, {,  \|,  (,  and
>          ).

So you can also use:

```
grep "then\|there" x.x
```

Since the parentheses are superfluous in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Bash's elegant simplicity seems to get lost in it's huge man page.

In addition to the excellent solutions above, I thought I'd try to give you a cheat sheet on **how bash parses and interprets statements**.  Then using this roadmap I'll parse the examples presented by the questioner to help you better understand why they don't work as intended.

---

*Note: Shell script lines are used directly.  Typed input-lines are first history-expanded.*

**Each bash line is first tokenized**, or in other words chopped into what are called **tokens**.  (Tokenizing occurs before all other expansions, including brace, tilde, parameter, command, arithmetic, process, word splitting, & filename expansion.)

A token here means a portion of the input line separated (delimited) by one of these special meta-characters:

```
space,  - White space...
tab, 
newline,

‘<’,    - Redirection & piping...
‘|’, 
‘>’
‘&’,    - And/Both < | > | >>  .or.  &<file descriptor>

‘;’,    - Command termination

‘(’,    - Subshell, closed by -     ‘)’
```

Bash uses many other special characters but only these 10 produce the initial tokens.

However because these meta-characters also sometimes must be used within a token, there needs to be a way to take away their special meaning.  This is called escaping.  Escaping is done either by quoting a string of one or more characters, (i.e. `'xx..'`, `"xx.."`), or by prefixing an individual character with a back-slash, (i.e. `\x`).  (It's a little more complicate than this because the quotes also need to be quoted, and because double quotes don't quote everything, but this simplification will do for now.)

*Don't confuse bash quoting with the idea of quoting a string of text, like in other languages.  What is in between quotes in bash are not strings, but rather sections of the input line that have meta-characters escaped so they don't delimit tokens.*

Note, there is an important difference between `'`, and `"`, but that's for another day.

The remaining unescaped meta-characters then become token separators.

**For example,**

```
$ echo "x"'y'\g
xyg

$ echo "<"'|'\>
<|>

$ echo x\; echo y
x; echo y
```

In the first example there are two tokens produced by a space delimiter: `echo` and `xyz`.

Likewise in the 2nd example.

In the third example the semicolon is escaped, so there are 4 tokens produced by a space delimiter, `echo`, `x;`, `echo`, and `y`.  The first token is then run as the command, and takes the next three tokens as input.  Note the 2nd `echo` is not executed.

---

The important thing to remember is that bash first looks for escaping characters (`'`, `"`, and `\`), and then looks for unescaped meta-character delimiters, in that order.

If not escaped then these 10 special characters serve as `token` delimiters.  Some of them also have additional meaning, but first and foremost, they are token delimiters.

---

**What grep expects**

In the example above grep needs these tokens, `grep`, `string`, `filename`.

The question's first try was:

> > $ grep (then|there) x.x

In this case `(`, `)` and `|` are unescaped meta characters and so serve to split the input into these tokens: `grep`, `(`, `then`, `|`, `there`, `)`, and `x.x`.  grep wants to see `grep`, `then|there`, and `x.x`.

The question's second try was:

> > grep "(then|there)" x.x

This tokenizes into `grep`, `(then|there)`, `x.x`.  You can see this if you swap out grep for echo:

> > echo "(then|there)" x.x
> >     (then|there) x.x