# How can I grep two things where one has option -w?

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expression

I have a **json** file from where I want to get the value of two items which are in an array using `grep`. Let's say I'm trying to get data from values `foo` and `bar`, the problem is that `bar`also matches `megabar`so I have to grep it with option `-w`.
The problem comes when trying to find them at the same time, as I have to `grep` for one value **OR** the other.
From [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82990/how-can-i-grep-for-this-or-that-2-things-in-a-file) question, I managed to get a bit closer to what I'm looking for but my result was something like:

```
grep -E '(foo|-w bar)' file
 "foo": "59766",
 "foo": "59770",
 "foo": "59774",
 "foo": "59778",
 "foo": "59782",
 "foo": "59786",
```

Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Does it need to be one `grep` call under all circumstances?

Comment: Yes, I need to have them related to each others. I'm trying to get `foo` and in the next line `bar` so I can work with them later

Comment: if you're parsing json, you probably should be using `jq` or `jsonpipe` or use a language (like `perl` or `python`) which has good json-parsing libraries.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [word boundary](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions) has a similar effect to `-w`, but can be used as part of the expression.

> ‘\b’
>      Match the empty string at the edge of a word.
>   [...]
>   ‘\<’
>      Match the empty string at the beginning of word.
>   ‘\>’
>      Match the empty string at the end of word.

To match `bar` only when it's the whole word, but `foo` anywhere (including inside longer words):

```
grep -E 'foo|\<bar\>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that foo would be used in the same context as foo and also match a full word, the easiest way is to do:

```
grep -E -w '(foo|bar)' file
```

Comment: As already answered 11 hours before, that's not what I'm looking for

Comment: @Alex since you did seem to want foo not to match a full word,  I looked for it several times, but since the question didn't specify it, seemed appropriate to note the easier answer nevertheless.