# How do I use Unix commands to print lines that contain Chinese characters OR lines that contain ###?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a text file and I want to use Unix commands (I don't care which) to print lines that contain a Chinese character OR contain the string ###.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41318257/2842962) has a grep command which prints out the lines containing Chinese characters

```
grep -P '[\p{Han}]' filename.txt
```

which I understand is a Perl regular expression.  And this prints out the lines containing ###:

```
grep '###' filename.txt
```

But I can't figure out how to combine (OR) them.  If I do `grep -e '###' -P '[\p{Han}]'` as I might expect [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37316/107463) would generalize, it doesn't print out the lines containing Chinese characters.

**Question**: How do I use Unix commands to print lines that contain Chinese characters OR lines that contain ###?

Oh, in case it helps, if the file contains

```
中文 keep this line
### keep this line
don't keep this line
```

it should output

```
中文 keep this line
### keep this line
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In general you'd combine multiple patterns using `-e pat1 -e pat2`, however at least for GNU grep version 3.4, the global `-P` option only permits a single pattern:

```
$ grep -P -e '[\p{Han}]' -e '###' filename.txt
grep: the -P option only supports a single pattern
```

So you need to place the alternation inside the regex:

```
grep -P -e '[\p{Han}]|###' filename.txt
```

or just

```
grep -P '\p{Han}|###' filename.txt
```

(the `-e` is optional in the case of a single pattern, and you don't need to use a bracket expression `[  ]` unless you have a **set** of characters or properties to match on).

---

Alternatively you may prefer to use Perl's regexps directly, ex.

```
perl -CDS -ne 'print if /\p{Han}/ or /###/' filename.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

GNU grep doesn't support multiple patterns when you use the `-P` option (except in the way steeldriver suggests), but [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) supports multiple patterns (and already has extended regex enabled):

```
rg -N -e '[\p{Han}]' -e '###' filename.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

If you only want lines containing `Han` script, `grep` for lines containing `<:Script<Han>>` character(s). Use the `|` to provide alternation with other regex patterns:

```perl
raku -ne '.put if .grep( / <:Script<Han>>  |  \#**3 / );'
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne '.put if .grep( / <:Script<Han>> / | / \#**3 / );'
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne '.put if .grep( / <:Script<Han>> / ) | .grep( / \#**3 / );'
```

Sample Input:

```
中文 keep this line
### keep this line
don't keep this line
```

Sample Output (all 3 code examples):

```
中文 keep this line
### keep this line
```

A short note on escaping characters within regexes in Raku:

Basically, all non-`alnum` characters have to be quoted or escaped to preserve their literal meaning. Unquoted or unescaped characters are presumed to have special meaning (e.g. `.` unescaped-dot means any character but `\.` escaped-dot means a literal dot character).

This rule applies whether an unescaped non-`alnum` character has an assigned regex meaning or not--effectively preserving an entire class of characters for future regex improvements.

https://raku.org