# Running 64bit OS , Find all 32bit programs on a system

Tags: find, executable

How should I locate all 32bit programs on my system ? I'm running a 64bit OS.

(There might be some , but I forget)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kinda crude, but should do the trick

```
find / -mount -type f -perm /111 -exec sh -c 'objdump -f {} | grep -q elf32 && echo {}' \;
```

- `-mount` keeps us on the `/` filesystem
- `-type f` restricts it to files only
- `-perm /111` restricts it to files with the executable bit
- then we run `objdump -f` on the file and `echo` the file name if `objdump` contains `elf32`

The first 3 filters are just so we narrow the results a bit and arent running `objdump` on every single thing.

Comment: 1) `find $(echo $PATH|sed -e 's/:/ /g')` will make it faster go; 2) `-mount` is kinda obsolete, it's `-xdev` now; 3) `objdump` takes bunch of files okay, so it's better feed it with them, reducing costs of exec calls: `objdump -f /bin/echo /bin/date |fgrep elf64` → `/bin/echo:     file format elf64-x86-64` `/bin/date:     file format elf64-x86-64`

Comment: Yeah, forgotten my favorite: avoid using `grep` when `fgrep` suffices — http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21020/how-can-i-test-whether-connection-to-the-given-host-port-is-established-in-bash/21060#comment49428_21060

Comment: poige, you should issue your own answer with those modifications.

Comment: @poige (1) restricts it too much in my opinion, `-mount` is more compatible than `-xdev`, doing it a file at a time makes it cleaner to show just the matching file name.

Comment: Cleaner? Slower — yes, but not cleaner. And what is a point to search every dir, except those where executables reside?

Comment: You say you know in advance where to find every directory that contains executables?

Comment: @poige yes, because obviously `/bin/echo: file format elf64-x86-64` is much cleaner than just showing `/bin/echo`... And where did I exclude the path 'where executables reside'?

Comment: @JodieC, yeah, I know exactly where SHELL would search for them. Don't ya?

Comment: @Patrick, what's your problem, dude — http://goo.gl/kMfwy ?

Comment: @poige As you say, your command would miss all executables not in $PATH, not satisfying the question.

Comment: @JodieC, OP decides what's applicable. My suggestion was to point what would be quite enough, but again, it depends on specific case requirements.

Comment: @poige OP decided "all 32bit programs"

Comment: @JodieC, well, then go check all tar.bz2 then, boy

Comment: @JodieC, moreover `-mount` prohibits descending into mounted FSes, which can be a place for `/opt` or `/usr/local`, or even whole `/usr`. So, you're screwed finally in your stubborn attempts. )

Comment: @poige, I said nothing about `-mount`, please stay on topic.

Comment: @JodieC, nice advice — apply it to yourself.

Comment: If you guys want to keep arguing about this, [take it to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/); comments aren't good for this sort of thing

Answer (score 1):

This will take forever:

```
find /|parallel -n100 file {}|grep "ELF 32.*executable"
```

It should work though.
You'll need to make sure you have `GNU parallel` installed

Comment: Running in parallel isn't a good idea here: this is an I/O-bound task, having multiple processes competing for the filesystem is more likely to slow the execution down. If you have several disks, you can get a speedup by running a separate `find` for each disk. Even with RAID-1, `find` is competing with `file` to some extent, but maybe `parallel -n2 file` would speed up a little.

Comment: `parallel -n100` won't spin off 100 tasks, it will only run one at a time sequentially, and give at most 100 arguments to each instance. See the max-args option in the [GNU parallel man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html)

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes. No point in invoking `parallel` if you're not going to use parallelism though.

Comment: Parallel has much better handling of special filenames. For instance, `find /|xargs -n100 -i file {}` would throw errors on the first filename with a single quote in it, while `GNU parallel` will happily plod along.

Comment: `find / -exec file {} +`

Comment: On my system that passed between 800 and 3500 arguments to each exec process. Good call.

Comment: @Gilles is right — no need in `parallel`. Both `find` and `xargs` have ASCIIZ encoding support (`-print0` and `-0` accordingly) to overcome troubles with delimiting characters in file names.

Comment: `GNU parallel` supports all of the `xargs` options and handles special characters without using NULs. See  [Differences between GNU Parallel and alternatives](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#differences_between_gnu_parallel_and_alternatives).

Comment: I still don't see why should one prefer it to more common find/xargs ASCIIZed.